# Appgyver Steroids + jQuery Mobile + CORS XHR

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cors, steroids

I've just started to play around with Appgyver Steroids apps and got stuck with CORS ajax requests.

I have no problems when the file making the request is under www/ folder, but as soon as I move it under app/views the request won't work anymore.

On IOS -simulator both locations work just fine, but on actual devices I get error status..

My server app replies with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header and I get correct results from a web browser.

Anyone know how to make requests work within app/* folders?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both the `app/` and `www/` folders are combined into the `dist/` folder during the `steroids make` process (automatic part of running `steroids connect`). They are treated equally by the devices, so everything should work correctly.

Are the files identical in the `dist/` folder? Do you set the view locations differently in `config/application.coffee`, e.g. `http://localhost/views/bananas/index.html` vs. `bananaIndex.html` (the first one loads via localhost, the second via File protocol). You can check the `window.location.href` attribute also.